# mysql select statement help needed

Tags: mysql

mysql Table column names:

```
ORGNAME  ( 10 distinct names )
BU     
FAMILY
opstep
```

ORGNAME IS DISTINCT
There can be more than 1 bu in each orgname

```
ORGNAME1 BU1
ORGNAME1 BU2
ORGNAME1 BU3
```

There is also more that 1 family in each bu

```
ORGNAME1 BU1 FAMILY1  count of opstep1
ORGNAME1 BU1 FAMILY1  count of opstep2
ORGNAME1 BU1 FAMILY1  count of opstep3

ORGNAME1 BU1 FAMILY2  count of opstep1
ORGNAME1 BU1 FAMILY2 count of opstep2
ORGNAME1 BU1 FAMILY2 count of opstep3
```

I need to the count of each opstep in each distinCt orgname,bu,and family. Hope this makes sence. Any help would be appreciated. Ive grouped and counted and just cant seem to get it correct...

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like:

```
SELECT ORGNAME, BU, FAMILY, COUNT(opstep)
GROUP BY ORGNAME, BU, FAMILY
```